# Create a program that inputs a regular expression and outputs strings that satisfy that regular expression

Tags: regex, computer-science

I think that the title accurately summarizes my question, but just to elaborate a bit.

Instead of using a regular expression to verify properties of existing strings, I'd like to use the regular expression as a way to *generate* strings that have certain properties.

**Note**: The function doesn't need to generate *every* string that satisfies the regular expression (cause that would be an infinite number of string for a lot of regexes).  Just a sampling of the many valid strings is sufficient.

How feasible is something like this?  If the solution is too complicated/large, I'm happy with a general discussion/outline. Additionally, I'm interested in any existing programs or libraries (.NET) that do this.

Comment: This would be an excellent learning / dev tool.

Comment: Take a look at matching an email address http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html and finding primes http://alicebobandmallory.com/articles/2007/03/30/find-primes-in-regexp    without giving up. ;)

Comment: I was going to point you to Regexp::Genex on CPAN, but then I realized it might have been written by you. :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well a regex is convertible to a DFA which can be thought of as a graph. To generate a string given this DFA-graph you'd just find a path from a start state to an end state. You'd just have to think about how you want to handle cycles (Maybe traverse every cycle at least once to get a sampling? n times?), but I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Most modern regex engines supports backreferences and it seems that those could make it really hard to produce a match. http://perl.plover.com/NPC/

Comment: http://osteele.com/tools/reanimator/???  - May help you along the path of realizing the conversion to a DFA

Comment: Another way to look at this would be to convert the DFA to a markov model. That way taking a random walk through the DFA is easy. At each point you randomly choose a transition and you only stop when you reach a terminating state or you have a string of a desired length.

A markov chain is very simple to represent as a square reachability matrix from states to states. If a state is reachable from some other state then there will be a non-zero value in their intersection in the matrix. 

To walk the DFA, just choose randomly from amongst the matches of the row of the current state.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by [traversing the DFA](http://compilers.iecc.com/comparch/article/99-05-141) (includes pseudocode) or else by walking the regex's abstract-syntax tree directly or converting to NFA first, as explained by [Doug McIlroy](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~doug/pubs.html): [paper](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~doug/nfa.ps.gz) and [Haskell code](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~doug/nfa.hs). (He finds the NFA approach to go faster, but he didn't compare it to the DFA.)

These all work on regular expressions without back-references -- that is, 'real' regular expressions rather than Perl regular expressions. To handle the extra Perl features it'd be easiest to add on a post-filter.

**Added:** [code for this](https://github.com/darius/peglet/blob/master/examples/regex.py) in Python, by Peter Norvig and me.

Answer (score 2):

This [utility on UtilityMill](http://utilitymill.com/utility/Regex_inverter) will invert some simple regexen.  It is based on [this example from the pyparsing wiki](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/invRegex.py).  The test cases for this program are:

```
[A-EA]
[A-D]*
[A-D]{3}
X[A-C]{3}Y
X[A-C]{3}\(
X\d
foobar\d\d
foobar{2}
foobar{2,9}
fooba[rz]{2}
(foobar){2}
([01]\d)|(2[0-5])
([01]\d\d)|(2[0-4]\d)|(25[0-5])
[A-C]{1,2}
[A-C]{0,3}
[A-C]\s[A-C]\s[A-C]
[A-C]\s?[A-C][A-C]
[A-C]\s([A-C][A-C])
[A-C]\s([A-C][A-C])?
[A-C]{2}\d{2}
@|TH[12]
@(@|TH[12])?
@(@|TH[12]|AL[12]|SP[123]|TB(1[0-9]?|20?|[3-9]))?
@(@|TH[12]|AL[12]|SP[123]|TB(1[0-9]?|20?|[3-9])|OH(1[0-9]?|2[0-9]?|30?|[4-9]))?
(([ECMP]|HA|AK)[SD]|HS)T
[A-CV]{2}
A[cglmrstu]|B[aehikr]?|C[adeflmorsu]?|D[bsy]|E[rsu]|F[emr]?|G[ade]|H[efgos]?|I[nr]?|Kr?|L[airu]|M[dgnot]|N[abdeiop]?|Os?|P[abdmortu]?|R[abefghnu]|S[bcegimnr]?|T[abcehilm]|Uu[bhopqst]|U|V|W|Xe|Yb?|Z[nr]
(a|b)|(x|y)
(a|b) (x|y)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it is trivially possible to write a regular expression that matches no possible strings, and I believe it is also possible to write a regular expression for which calculating a matching string requires an exhaustive search of possible strings of all lengths, you'll probably need an upper bound on requesting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to implement but definitely most CPU time intensive approach would be to simply brute force it.
Set up a character table with the characters that your string should contain and then just sequentially generate strings and do a Regex.IsMatch on them.

Comment: For a regex of any significant complexity this would probably take an unreasonable amount of processing power.

Comment: That could easily finish after the end of time.

Comment: According to the back of my napkin, if you can do 100,000 regex tests per second, you will be able to test all 12-character strings possible on a standard US keyboard by roughly the same time the Sun will burn out.

Comment: well, I didn't say that it will be fast or practical but it would be easy to implement and for short strings it would be a feasible approach :P

Comment: @Rex M, You might upgrade your cpu before the sun burns out, so make sure the program can be halted+resumed

Comment: also, you can easily parallelize it, so e.g. on a dual quad core machine it would only take 1/8th of ~5.5bln years, not accounting for quantum computing in the near future

Answer (score 0):

I, personally, believe that this is the holy grail of reg-ex. If you could implement this -- even only 3/4 working -- I have no doubt that you'd be rich in about 5 minutes.

All joking aside, I'm not sure that what you are truly going after is feasible. Reg-Ex is a very open, flexible language and giving the computer enough sample input to truly and accurately find what you need, is probably not feasible.

If I'm proven wrong, I wish kudos to that developer.

To look at this from a different perspective, this is almost (not quite) like giving a computer it's output, and having it -- based on that -- write a program for you. This is a little overboard, but it kind of illustrates my point.